# How to modify the LoadConvert Apex payload?

Tags: api, salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-development

I've written a trigger under the LeadConvert update event as follows:

```
trigger WebhookSenderTriggerLeadConvert on Lead (after update) {
    if (Trigger.new.size() == 1) {
        if (Trigger.old[0].isConverted == false && Trigger.new[0].isConverted == true) {
            if (Trigger.new[0].ConvertedAccountId != null) {
                String url = 'https://mydomain.io';
                String content = WebhookSender.jsonContent(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
                WebhookSender.callout(url, content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works for me on a dev Salesforce, and in the payload I correctly receive:

```
{
    "new":[
        {
            "attributes":{
                "type":"Lead",
                "url":"/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Lead/B00000000000000000"
            },
            "Id":"B00000000000000000",
            ...(+30 more fields)
        }
    ],
    "old":[
        {
            "attributes":{
                "type":"Lead",
                "url":"/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Lead/B00000000000000000"
            },
            "Id":"B00000000000000000",
            ...(+30 more fields)
        }
    ],
    "userId":"A00000000000000000"
}
```

However in another third party Salesforce account I get the following:

```
{
    "new":[
        {
            "attributes":{
                "type":"Lead",
                "url":"/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Lead/C00000000000000000"
            },
            ...(9 more fields)
        }
    ],
    "old":[
        {
            "attributes":{
            },
            ...(9 more fields)
        }
    ],
    "userId":"D00000000000000000"
}
```

I've obfuscated a lot of the fields here as a lot of it is sensitive, but what i'm unable to determine is what exactly causing a large portion of fields in the third-party Salesforce to not be there, including the Id field, where in the dev Salesforce everything is present.

Is there anything that may be doing this?

EDIT:
Posting WebhookSender, as it's been brought up in comments

```
public class WebhookSender {
    public static String jsonContent(List<Object> triggerNew, List<Object> triggerOld) {
        String newObjects = '[]';
        if (triggerNew != null) {
            newObjects = JSON.serialize(triggerNew);
        }

        String oldObjects = '[]';
        if (triggerOld != null) {
            oldObjects = JSON.serialize(triggerOld);
        }
        String userId = JSON.serialize(UserInfo.getUserId());

        String content = '{"new": ' + newObjects + ', "old": ' + oldObjects + ', "userId": ' + userId + '}';
        return content;
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void callout(String url, String content) {
        Http h = new Http();

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'someKey');
        req.setBody(content);

        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {h.send(req);}
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> ParseRequest(RestRequest req) {
        String body = req.requestBody.toString();
        Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(body);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, is the WebhookSender class identical in both? Does it dump all fields it received to JSON or does it contain some security-related code such as "[stripInaccessible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_stripInaccessible.htm)"? Maybe the fields are there but your Profile doesn't see them so strip... cuts them out?

Can it be that your dev org simply has 20+ custom fields in Lead table more than the other org?

Are the fields you're missing coming from managed package? They'd have `namespace__FieldName__c` format, with 4 underscores total. Maybe the package isn't installed. If you know the fields are there but your user doesn't have license for that managed package - it's possible they'll be hidden.

Comment: WebhookSender is basically identical, only difference being a key. All fields should be getting dumped to JSON. I don't think a stripInaccessible is used anywhere. The dev org has 28 and the third-party has more, so seeing as few as I do is odd to me. None of it is a managed package, it all exists in Custom Code Classes/Triggers

Comment: I meant fields on Lead that could be coming from managed package / something you don't have a license to. Check your Profile in the 2nd org, are all fields on Lead marked as readable? If the field is a Lookup - you'd also need to check if you have at least Read right to the object being looked up to
If you run your code in 2nd org with dev console open / debug logging - how does Trigger.new look like, lots of fields or only handful matching your JSON?